# control memory alignment in python ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm looking into using ctypes for using C functions manipulating SSE (__m128) data that have to be aligned on 16 bytes boundaries.

I could not find a simple way to control the alignment of memory allocated by ctypes, so, right now, I'm making ctypes call a C function that provides a correctly aligned memory buffer.

The problem I have with this approach is that I have to manually *explicitly* release this memory to prevent it from being leaked.

Is there a way to control the alignment of memory allocated by ctypes ? or is there a way to register a cleanup function to release memory allocated by a C function called by ctypes (apart from standard python operator **__*del*__**) ?

What is the best path to follow ?

Answer (score 4):

I've been taking some time to investigate, I came up with a function that should allow me to allocate arbitrary aligned memory with ctypes, basically relying on the fact that ctypes should keep a reference on the unaligned memory buffer, while having an instance starting at an aligned position in the buffer.

Still have to test this in production.

```
import ctypes

def ctypes_alloc_aligned(size, alignment):

  bufSize = size+(alignment-1)
  raw_memory = bytearray(bufSize)

  ctypes_raw_type = (ctypes.c_char * bufSize)
  ctypes_raw_memory = ctypes_raw_type.from_buffer(raw_memory)

  raw_address = ctypes.addressof(ctypes_raw_memory)
  offset = raw_address % alignment
  offset_to_aligned = (alignment - offset) % alignment

  ctypes_aligned_type = (ctypes.c_char * (bufSize-offset_to_aligned))
  ctypes_aligned_memory = ctypes_aligned_type.from_buffer(raw_memory, offset_to_aligned)

  return ctypes_aligned_memory
```

Comment: If I want to create append not cut buffer? ex: I have 6192-bytes buffer input and I will get 8192 buffer output(because I append it to 4096*2=8192-bytes buffer)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that `c_ulonglong` (64 bit) must be 64-bit aligned; it's a start. Then the [doc suggests that you can use `_pack_`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#structure-union-alignment-and-byte-order) to control alignment of structures. These two are not *exactly* what you want, but by combining them you can allocate 8-byte aligned structs without holes.

Let's assume a struct with with 3 8-byte aligned elements `.v0`, `.v1`, `.v2`. Use `addressof()` to see if the struct is 16-byte aligned. If it is, use `.v0` and `.v1` for your 128-bit value; if it's not, use `.v1` and `.v2`.

Comment: I just gave `_pack_` a try, and it seems that it can't handle values other than 1, 2, 4 - would it handle 16, it would be my answer. Regarding your `addressof` trick, thanks but actually any C pointer arithmetics can do the trick ; I'd like to 'cleaner' than this.